# Error using Install-DbaInstance with AnalysisServices

Tags: dbatools

I have already asked the question [here](https://github.com/dataplat/dbatools/discussions/9177), but unfortunately did not get an answer.

I recently started getting an error when using dbatools.
When I try to perform an installation via "Install-DbaInstance" and specify the parameter "AnalysisServices" (-Feature Engine,FullText,IntegrationServices,ReportingServices,AnalysisServices) i get the following message after a short time:
"Installation failed with exit code -2068578304. Expand 'ExitMessage' and 'Log' property to find more details."

How can I solve the problem?

Greetings,
Frank